# Pentaho Report Engine. Error while generating the report. Unable to locate the key column in the dataset

Tags: parameters, report, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I have created a report with Pentaho Report Designer, version 7.1.
The report was built with a subreport, that takes data from a CDA data source, already defined on the server.
I'm able to see the PDF preview from the report designer, with the correct data retrieved from CDA.
I succesfully uploaded the report to the Pentaho BI Server, version 7.1.
But, once I try to open the report from the server, I get, in the console, the message

> **Fatal Error** Error parsing parameter information.

The Tomcat log reports the error message

> 2018-10-11 17:48:52,023 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.http.api.resources.GeneratorStreamingOutput] Error generating content from content generator with id [parameter]
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate the key column in the dataset.

I double checked for eventually mispelled parameters in Pentaho Report Designer, but everything seems ok.

The only almost useful link I found was related to a slightly different problem:
[Unable to locate the value column in the dataset](https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/136288-Unable-to-locate-the-value-column-in-the-data-set/)

Is there anybody else that experienced the same problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Update: I noticed that the problem arises when using CDA as datasource. Changing to another type of data source, i.e. JDBC query, everything works fine. How can I keep using CDA in my report?

Comment: Also metadata work well, but CDA still not...

Answer (score 0):

Some of its parameters are using the display or value field, a field that does not exist in the query.

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment to the question/other answer.